# Servlet mapping Issue wtih mvc resources spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I have an issue with `mvc:resources`

My `main-servlet.xml`

```
    **
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    **
```

When I comment the `mvc:resources` lines everything (else) starts working magically. But when I uncomment the lines, ONLY the resources work. While compiling, log says that ONLY css/** and images/** were mapped and that there is no other mapping.

Web.xml File :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/css/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/**</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried putting 2 dispatcher servlets but that doesn't working either. The other servlet gets read and does get mapped but the request defaults to the main servlet.

Compilation log AFTER commenting /css/** and /images/** from web.xml :

```
    **
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
    INFO: Mapped URL path [/images/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
    Nov 26, 2013 11:40:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
    INFO: Mapped URL path [/css/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1'
    Nov 26, 2013 11:40:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'resources': initialization completed in 220 ms
    Nov 26, 2013 11:40:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'main'
    Nov 26, 2013 11:40:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
   **
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'main': initialization completed in 234 ms
    Nov 26, 2013 11:40:40 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
    INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
    Nov 26, 2013 11:40:40 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
    INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
    Nov 26, 2013 11:40:53 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
    WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/KT/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'main'
```

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't work :( . Putting up the compilation log now

Comment: Note that you shouldn't call it _compilation_. It's not compilation. It's startup/bootstrap logs.

Comment: What is the _everything (else)_ that starts working?

Comment: basically the other mappings in the web.xml file. When I try to access myapp/add with mvc:resources commented I can access it whereas i cannot access it when it's uncommented. Apache give me a 404 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that none of your controllers will be registered with your current setup. You need to add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to your context so that Spring registers them with the `DispatcherServlet`.

Your `main` `DispatcherServlet` should also simply be mapped to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The others are redundant.

Comment: I believe you're right. I added that line and tried to compile. I get this error in the startup logs. "Line 19 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/main-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'context:component-scan'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":message-converters, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":argument-resolvers, ...,  is expected." I'm a newbie to Spring so thanks for bearing with me

Comment: I moved mvc:anootation-driven one line down (below the context:component scan). Now I get the same error that the "bean" (next line after mvc-annotation driven) has an issue

Comment: I suppose it needed an end tag </mvc:annotation-driven>. It removed that error but got me another error. I'll post the log

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered but I ran into a bunch of issues while solving it so I wanna leave a few resolution steps just in case someone comes looking with similar problems :

1st and initial issue : mvc:resources what misbehaving (details in question)
Solution : Solved exactly as the accepted answer suggested. (

2nd Issue (see 1st stack trace) : Occurs when you don't have a closing tag for )
Solution : add " / " at the end or add  right after  (also the accepted answer has it correct)

3rd Issue (2nd (last) stack trace) : Occurrs when you don't have the following dependency :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also. If you're using Tika & Solrj togather, select the sl4j-api with the higher version. Selecting the lower version causes a whole bunch of other problems (sorry no stack trace).

My versions : Solr 3.6.2, Solrj 4.4.0, Tika 1.4.